# Swift optional in case where statement

Tags: switch-statement, where-clause, option-type, swift-playground

Doing a course the other day and one of the attendants tried something out and it came up with an interesting bug.

How can this provide an result when it is switching on a case with value `nil`?

```
func canDrink(age: Int?, country: String)->bool{
    switch (age, country){
    case (let anAge, _) where anAge < 5: //playground still says anAge is an optional
        return false
    default:
        return true
    }
}
canDrink(15,"UK")  // Returns true
canDrink(4,"UK")   // Returns false
canDrink(nil,"UK") // Also returns false not an error.
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

To provide a bit more context, per your comment. There is nothing invalid about comparing against an optional:

```
var d: Int? = 4
if d < 5 {} // true
```

and if the optional is `nil` it will still be a true value:

```
var d: Int? = nil
if d < 5 {} // still true
```

Why is this? Well a `nil` value is literally `.None` (`if .None < 5`) (see below) and in this case `5` is definitely greater than `.None`.

#### Original

The problem here is that `let anAge` is an optional Int (as you pointed out). If you inspect it you will see this (image for reference):

[image]

If you take a look at the optional definition you will see an option is an enum with two types (`None` and `Some`). So we can just check against `Some` to make sure it has a value:

```
func canDrink(age: Int?, country: String) -> Bool {
    switch (age, country) {
    case (.Some, _) where age < 5: // We now know that `age` is some value
        return false
    default:
        return true
    }
}

canDrink(15,"UK")  // Returns true
canDrink(4,"UK")   // Returns false
canDrink(nil,"UK") // Now returns true, since this is a `.None` age
```

Comment: I get that is the fix and I stuck in an if. I was just wondering how a comparison against a optional was possible with no compiler or runtime error.

Comment: @Little_John, updated answer. Basically optional comparison is valid.

Comment: @Little_John, also, I am assuming you want your func to return `false` if the age is nil. You could just reverse the cases: `case (.None, _) return false` followed by the default `return age >= 5`. Since if it reaches the default `age` will no longer be an optional.

Comment: I still think that is a language flaw as although `.none` is no valve which should be evaluate like `null` in other lanuages but I think that as optionals throw errors when `nil` elsewhere why comparison is exempt.